# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified winform c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

```
SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Vows(MemberID, VowAmount, VowDate, Description) Values (@MemberID, @vowAmount, @vowDate, @vowDesc)", con);

SqlCommand storedprocedure = new SqlCommand("UPDATEINCOME", con);
storedprocedure.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
storedprocedure.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IncomeDate", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = vowdateTime.Text;

SqlCommand insertStoredProcedure = new SqlCommand("InsertIncomeDate", con);
insertStoredProcedure.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

insertStoredProcedure.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IncomeDate", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = vowdateTime.Text;
insertStoredProcedure.Parameters.Add("@IncomeDate", SqlDbType.Date).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
insertStoredProcedure.Parameters.Add("@IncomeDate", SqlDbType.Date).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

Here are my codes and I get the error that:

> Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

```
cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", vowMemID.Text);
cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vowAmount", vowAmount.Text);
cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vowDate", vowdateTime.Text);
cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vowDesc", vowDescBox.Text);
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                   

insertStoredProcedure.ExecuteNonQuery();  // error occurs here
insertStoredProcedure.Parameters.Clear();

storedprocedure.ExecuteNonQuery();    // and here
storedprocedure.Parameters.Clear();
```

These are the stored procedures:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UPDATEINCOME] 
    (@IncomeDate date, @VowAmount money) 
AS
    Declare @TitheAmount money
    Declare @OfferingAmount money
    Declare @IncomeTotal money

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select VowDate from Vows where VowDate = @IncomeDate)
    BEGIN
        set @VowAmount = '0'
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        set @VowAmount = (Select VowAmount from Vows where VowDate = @IncomeDate)
    END

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select OfferingDate from Offering where OfferingDate = @IncomeDate)
    BEGIN
        set @OfferingAmount = '0'
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
       set @OfferingAmount = (Select OfferingAmount from Offering where OfferingDate = @IncomeDate)
    END

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select TitheDate from Tithe where TitheDate = @IncomeDate)
    BEGIN
        set @TitheAmount = '0'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       Set @TitheAmount = (Select TitheAmount from Tithe where TitheDate = @IncomeDate)
    END

    Set @IncomeTotal = @TitheAmount + @VowAmount + @OfferingAmount

    UPDATE IncomeReport 
    SET Amount = @IncomeTotal 
    WHERE IncDATE = @IncomeDate
```

The `UPDATEINCOME` stored procedure updates the `IncomeReport` table. It sums up all the amounts for a particular date specified here as the `IncomeDate` and inserts the total into the `IncomeReports`.

Meanwhile the `INsertDate` stored procedure checks to see if the `IncomeReport` table has the date that the 'cmmd' command intends to insert an amount under. If it doesn't, it iInserts the date gotten from the `IncomeDate` also. This then allows for the `UPDATEINCOME` to insert an amount into that table where the date is `@IncomeDate`.

Comment: You don't actually show `InsertIncomeDate`, so we can't comment on whether the parameters are appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding two `@IncomeDate` parameters. Don't do that ;p

```
storeproc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IncomeDate", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = vowdateTime.Text;
...
storeproc.Parameters.Add("@IncomeDate", SqlDbType.Date).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

and (as Sriram notes in comments):

```
storedprocedure.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IncomeDate", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = vowdateTime.Text;
...
storedprocedure.Parameters.Add("@IncomeDate", SqlDbType.Date).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

If you want, you could capture the result of `Parameters.Add`:

```
var p = storeproc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IncomeDate", SqlDbType.Date));
p.Value = vowdateTime.Text;
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

But `Input` is the default *anyway*.

Frankly, though, you're making this hard. I strongly recommend a tool like "dapper" here:

```
DateTime when = ...
decimal amount = ...
connection.Execute("UPDATEINCOME",
    new { IncomeDate = when, VowAmount = amount },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

*job done*.

Comment: I'm very confused with that. Did you noticed both are different variables `storeproc` and `storedprocedure`? Both are pointing different commands :(

Comment: @SriramSakthivel look again... (I've clarified it in an edit)

Comment: Yes, I overlooked it. Also OP does the same mistake for `storedprocedure` variable.

Comment: Refer line number 4 and 8 both adds `@IncomeDate` to  `storedprocedure`

Comment: Simply put: This code is a mess. OP should really refactor it. Atleast separate the unrelated code blocks with line breaks would make it more readable.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel agree entirely; hence my final "dapper" example which would replace just about all of it, in addition to getting all the `using` etc correct.

Comment: @EmmanuelGiftEkwemuka please do take under advisement what Sriram and I are saying though: your data access code looks really really messy, and it impacts on readability and maintenance. You're also *making your life unnecessarily hard* in the process. If I was being picky, code that talks to both the UI and the database in the same method is also usually a very bad sign.